# Is $n(n+1)$ ever a factorial?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Brocard's problem asks if $(n-1)(n+1)$ is ever a factorial. My question is similar: is $n(n+1)$ ever a factorial?

This can be seen as the special case $k=2$ of the question: for $2\le k\le n-2,$ when is $n!/(n-k)!$ a factorial? I know of only one case, $10!/7!=6!$ (see [A109095](https://oeis.org/A109095)).

I have verified the absence of solutions for $n<10^{85}$ so their absence seems certain. Can this be proved? (Has it been?) I would also be interested in information on the general problem.

Edit: Having recently regained some interest in this problem, I verified it up to $m\le10^9$ or $n<10^{4282852761}$ using modular arithmetic to 37 large primes. (Each value of $m$ required 37 modular multiplications and an average of 2 Legendre symbols.)

Comment: you must have meant $n>2?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Yes.

Comment: Is your computer verification for the $k=2$ case specifically or the general arbitrary $k$ situation?

Comment: Up to a factor of $2$ it seems that not much is known, at least according to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40945/triangular-factorials

Comment: If $n$ or $n+1$ is prime, and $n>2$, then their is no solution since any solution of the form $k!=n(n+1)$ must satisfy $k<n$. This means that the prime must divide exactly one the factors of $k!$, which cannot happen.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446904/four-fractions-of-certain-factorials-give-another-factorial is related to the second paragraph question.

Comment: @anon: For the k=2 case. I couldn't reach nearly as far on the general case...!

Comment: this is equivalent to finding integers solutions to $4n!+1 = m^2$. the ABC conjecture implies that Brocard's problem has finitely many solutions, and I believe it should apply here just as well.

Comment: Once you have excluded small $m$ in $n(n+1)=m!$, we find that $n\equiv 0$ or $\equiv -1\pmod {p}$ for all primes $p\le m$. In fact the same holds for all prime powers $p^r$ with $r=\lfloor \frac mp\rfloor +\ldots$. Watching these congruences even just for growin powers of $2,3,5$ surely allows one to search (relatively) fast to $^0^{85}$ or the like - but if *way* less than $10^{85}$ cases had to be actually tested, the number $10^{85}$ becomes "less impressive" in terms of likeniness of truth for all $n$, I'm afraid

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes, that was the method I used, except that I used prime powers rather than primes. But it turns out it's more efficient to just iterate through factorials...

Comment: A short computer search suggests there is no solution for $m\leq 10^5$ (note, that's $m$, not $n$).

Comment: @PeterKošinár: Thanks, I just finished the same check.

Comment: This question has been asked (but not conclusively answered) before, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350637/find-the-positive-integer-solutions-of-m-nn1, also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39210/solve-in-positive-integers-n-mm1

Comment: a triangular number can be a factorial like $15*(15+1)/2=120=5!$ but this makes it difficult for twice a triangular number to be a factorial.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem.  I don't have a solution just some observations.

$n$ and $n+1$ are relatively prime via Euclid's algorithm:

$$\gcd(n+1,n) = \gcd(n,1) = \gcd(1,0) = 1$$

The two sequential numbers, therefore, share no common factors.  Only one of the numbers is even (for obvious reasons), so it must contain $2$ to some power $x$.  However, it does not contain all powers of $2$.  The powers it may contain follow a sequence:  $1,3,4,7,8,10,11,15,16,18,19,22,23,25,26,31,32,34,35,38....$

For example, $4 \times (\text{only odd factors})$ will never produce a factorial.  However, $4 \times (3 \times 5 \times 7) = (4 \times 5) \times (3 \times 7) = (20)(21).$

I don't know if it's headed in the correct direction, but if you could use this fact to cover the entire set of integers you could prove that $n\times(n+1)$ never is a factorial except for the trivial case already mentioned.

Comment: Will it be prudent to consider legendres equality and show that it can not hold for a number (n+1)n

Comment: Why cant the expression for [inverse gamma function](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2012-140-04/S0002-9939-2011-11023-2/S0002-9939-2011-11023-2.pdf) be used, to shew that an inverse can not exist for n(n+1)

Answer (score 1):

Solving a quadratic for $ n $ and choosing a positive root, we get:

$ 2n=\sqrt {1+4k!}-1 $

So all we need to show is that the only cases in which $ 1+4k! $ is a perfect square are when $ k=2 $ and $ k=3 $.

**P.S.:** Sorry for my non-number-theory notation style.

Comment: How do you prove that $4k!+1$ is a perfect square only when $k=2$ and $k=3$?